# Where to write logic related to component that doesn't affect the UI directly

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have a component which contains a textarea. Whenever I enter text I run a set of validations against the text and depending upon results I update the UI. You can assume the code to be like this:

```
onTextChange(e) {
    const results = this.runValidations(e.target.value)
}
```

Now, the problem is `this.runValidations` is like 100 lines of code sitting right there in the component but doesn't affect the UI directly and is specific only to the component and its child components. But, it makes my component file bloated.

So, is there any convention that other people follow in their React-Redux apps to handle such logical code that is specific to the component but is not part of the UI logic? Where do they place such code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the end of the day, most business logic doesn't have a lot to do with React/Redux - so they can usually be shovelled out into their own utility functions or classes. Which is great for a few reasons

- a) easier to test because it hasn't zero linkage to React/Redux and
- b) keeps your actions light, and
- c) more encapsulated - having minimal knowledge of react/redux is not a bad thing.

It's all just Javascript - there is nothing wrong with importing custom business classes or utility functions.

**Edit**

My folder structure will typically look like:

- my-component

  - child-components

    - Child1.js
    - _Child1.scss
    - Child2.js
    - _Child2.scss
  - helpers

    - util1.js // with a single default export
    - util2.js // with a single default export
  - _MyComponent.scss
  - MyComponent.js
  - MyComponent.spec

Where child components are (or should) only be pulled into this component. Ie. they shouldn't be used by other components.

This hashnode article also has a great structure if you are using redux as well: [hashnode.com/post/tips-for-a-better-redux-architecture-lessons-for-enterprise-scale-civrlqhuy0keqc6539boivk2f](http://hashnode.com/post/tips-for-a-better-redux-architecture-lessons-for-enterprise-scale-civrlqhuy0keqc6539boivk2f)

Comment: Yes, thats what I am planning to do right now. Can I ask you what kind of folder structure do you follow while implementing these utility classes? What would you recommend? Currently, I have a type based folder structure with separate folders for components, reducers, utils, constants, actions etc.

Comment: Sure I will add it to the answer so I can format it a bit nicer than the comment

Comment: @FurkanO Yeah ducks is pretty cool approach. Have a look at the article I just linked into the answer - it kind of uses the duck approach but on a grander scale

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are missing the concept of **components** vs **containers** (or **dumb components** vs **smart components**, as some like to name it). Basically, it is a good practice to apart your business logic from you pure presentational components.

Have a look at [Presentational and Container Components](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0#.43f7cju6n), by Dan Abramov.

Comment: The component I am talking about is a smart component.